# Transfer binary image data when form submission is encoded as JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-uploading

I have several fields in an *HTML* form including a file field which I'd like to use to upload images.  The problem I am facing is that the *API* is expecting the form-data in its entirety to be encoded as JSON - how can this format accomodate an image as a binary file?

Here is what I'm looking at so far:

```html
<form method="POST" name="myForm" onsubmit="uploadPost()">
    Name:<input type="text" id="name">
    Location:<input type="text" id="location">
    Image: <input id="image_file" name="image_file[]" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

```
function uploadPost(){
    var uName = $("#name").val();
    var uLoc = $("#location").val();
    var apiUrl="https://example.com/upload";
    var image_file = $('#image_file').get(0).files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image_file", image_file);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: apiUrl,
        data: 
        {
            name: email,
            location: password,
            image: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        },
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function(data){
                alert(data.message.image);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I don't see in your `data` definition where you include the information from `image_file[]` or your variable `image_file`.

Comment: When you perform the post, do you encounter an error? What is returned?

Comment: Is there any other solution to upload image file on json api?

Comment: it return Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation and when I am alerting the  file variable then it alert Object File.

Comment: First, I suspect you saw this very similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload Which version of JQuery are you using and what version browser are you expecting?

Comment: ok thanks. I am going to see it.